# How can I resolve this issue regarding upgradation of pip on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: pip, ubuntu-16.04

Here is what happened.I even tried to remove pip, but it shows the same problem.My python version is 2.7.12

```
saikat@saikat:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: I guess you installed python with a package manager (apt?). So you have no user rights on the /usr/* folder hierarchy. Prefix your command with `sudo` (`sudo pip install...`) could help but can cause other problems (wrong installation paths since the home folder is different)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/e7/a8/7556133689add8d1a54c0b14aeff0acb03c64707ce100ecd53934da1aa13/pip-8.1.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf pip-8.1.2.tar.gz
cd pip-8.1.2
sudo python setup.py install
```

It should help

Comment: Why downloading and installing the already installed version again?